# Feature Selection - Comparing Performance of different size datasets

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

If I have training data `X`, with `N` features, and I do feature selection, and discover `n` of `N` (where `n < N`) are basically relevant to target data `Y` (the other `N - n` are basically irrelevant), how do I assess the impact of feature selection of a feature selected dataset, `n` features, to full dataset, `N` features?

Do I compare the performance on an identical neural network trained on "XN" vs. "Xn"? For example, if `N = 20`, say, and `n = 5`, and if I have a model with 3 layers, 18 nodes each, and an activation function `F1`. Do I feed the same model with 20 and 5 inputs respectively? (Comparing well a model of 3 layers, 18 nodes, `active_func = F1`, learns for 20 and 5 input features). **"apples and apples"**

Or do I, for example, do a hyper parameter optimisation in both, so that I may be testing the impact of feature selection on my ML performance, with for "XN" a model of 3 layers, 18 nodes, `active_func = F1` ("the optimal hyper parameters for this dataset"), and another with 2 layers, 12 nodes, `active_func = F2`, ("the optimal hyperparameters for model with dataset `n = 5`"). **"apples and oranges"**

? :) Thanks!